# Absolutely continuous functions that don't have an integrable bound

Tags: real-analysis

What are some examples of functions that are absolutely continuous, but are not bounded above by any integrable function?

What I am interested in is how the presence of this integrable bound affects the absolute continuity of the associated value function.

An integrable function, is a function which when (Riemann) integrated over its domain, yields a finite number (< $\infty$).

Sorry, I didn't realize how vaguely worded this question is. Here's attempt #2, do there exist $f(x,t)$, where $t$ is a parameter, such $f(x,\cdot)$ is absoultely continuous, but $\not\exists B(t)$, integrable, such that $\sup_{x} |f_{2}(x,t)| < B(t)$ for almost all $t$?

Comment: What is meant by integrable function?  Continuous functions are integrable over bounded intervals, and this seems to me all that one could hope to be true.  E.g. $y=x$ is absolutely continuous on every finite interval $[a,b]$ and also integrable there.

Answer (score 1):

Of maps $\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$, how about $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = \ln(1+|x|)$, $h(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$?

I'm not sure what to make of your second paragraph.  None of these are integrable, so no everywhere larger function is integrable.  ($f$ is the only one that is "close", but its positive part is not integrable, nor is its negative part.)  In fact, the constant function $h:\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}:x \mapsto 1$ is absolutely continuous, positive, and not integrable, so no everywhere larger function is integrable.